# Ember component creation error in 2.10

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components, ember-testing, ember-addon

When I do Ember.Component.Create() in an unit test for mixin i get this error.
I was upgrading ember from 1.13 to 2.10, this test worked fine in 1.13 but in 2.10 I get this error. Looks like in 2.10 ember component init requires an app instance.

```
Died on test #1     at Module.callback (http://localhost:4200/assets/tests.js:250:19)
    at Module.exports (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:131:32)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:30:18)
    at TestLoader.require (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:7104:7)
    at TestLoader.loadModules (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:7096:14)
    at Function.TestLoader.load (http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:7126:22)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:7009:18: Cannot instantiate a component without a renderer. Please ensure that you are creating <(subclass of Ember.Component):ember210> with a proper container/registry.@ 9 ms
Source:     
Error: Cannot instantiate a component without a renderer. Please ensure that you are creating <(subclass of Ember.Component):ember210> with a proper container/registry.
    at Class.init (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:51954:15)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50175:22)
    at Class.init (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50443:19)
    at Class.superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50175:22)
    at Class.init (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50493:19)
    at Class.superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50175:22)
    at Class.exports.default._emberMetal.Mixin.create._Mixin$create.init (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:51000:17)
    at Class.superWrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50175:22)
    at Class.init (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:17472:19)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:50175:22)
```

Few things I have tried:

- To startApp() in setup and destroy, similar to integration testi
  ng
- To override init but init always requires _super() to be called
- Tried to execute in integration testing environment where application is created

Comment: It seems to be 2.10.x specific. I'm not getting this on 2.9.1, 2.8.2 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to do `renderer: this.render` or other options but nothing worked, finally based on the lead I got [here](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-component-creation-error-in-2-10/12087/2)

I did `renderer: {}` and it worked just fine.

There are other good solutions in the link too but its not needed in my scenario since I am not rendering anything.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if unit testing a component required `Ember.Component.Create()` at 1.13; but you should not create the component yourself during unit testing of components now; at least this is what I learned during dealing with Ember.

You should use `moduleForComponent` from `ember-qunit` with `unit: true` parameter and get the component simply with `this.subject();` inside the test method.

I have created a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/53e5b6958f868acbf50f4af1125ed71c?openFiles=tests.unit.components.my-component-test.js%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs) for you to illustrate unit testing of a component with a mixin. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the effort but i am aware of how to unit test component having done that countless times. This is an edge case where i am unit testing a mixin and i needed to create a component

Comment: sorry; I did not understand that from your question :( just for curiosity why do you need a component while unit testing a mixin?